# Button event that will create a folder along with subfolders

Tags: c#

This is the code I have that should create a folder that I name through a textbox, although no folder is created when I do this action, I am looking for a way that whenever I click the button, a main folder is created along with subfolders that will be automatically named.

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!(Directory.Exists(@"C:\Documents\" + textBox1.Text)))
    {    
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Documents\" + textBox1.Text);
        label1.Text = "Directory" + textBox1 + " was created!";
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = "Directory" + textBox1 + "was not created";
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you click the button - are you getting an error?

Comment: when I select the button it says 'DirectorySystem.Windows.Forms.Textbox, Text: test was created!' but no folder is created in the directory

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)"

Comment: @jacko10101 This might sound really dumb, but don't you mean to create the directory under `C:\Users\{username}\Documents`?

Comment: yes that now creates the folder thanks, any idea on how to create subfolders in that folder in the same method?

Comment: @jacko10101 I just posted an answer that should provide you with that information as well

Comment: You should use `Path.Combine()` insatead of concatenating strings when combining paths. This will take care of the seperators. https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue isn't that the directory is not being created, but rather that it isn't being created where you think it is. According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=net-5.0), the `Directory.CreateDirectory` function will create a directory or subdirectories unless they already exist. Therefore, unless an exception is thrown, the directory was either created or it already exists.

So then, where is it? Simply put, in `C:/Documents`. Where do you expect it? In the User's "My Documents" library, which is actually located in `C:/Users/{username}/Documents`. Therefore, your code should actually be:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var subpath = "..." // get this from your event args or somewhere else
    var fullPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users", Environment.UserName, "Documents", textBox1.Text);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(fullPath);
    if (!Directory.Exists(fullPath))
    {    
        label1.Text = $"Directory {textBox1.Text} was created!";
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = $"Directory {textBox1.Text} was not created";
    }
}
```